# React Native: hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native'

export default class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  }
  render () {
    const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');
    return (<View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        value={value}
      />
    </View>);
  }
}
```

Learning React Native, encountered this error, how to correct the above code?

The official example of my imitation: [https://reactnative.cn/docs/textinput](https://reactnative.cn/docs/textinput.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using class component and hooks can only be used in functional components.
Either use `setState` or convert the class to functional, like so

```
export default const Home = props => {

// your code


}
```

Moreover, it is not a good idea to set state inside the render, so you should take it outside.